# Laravel implementing a cookie less Session for mobile applications

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel-4, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to Implement a Session Driver (lets say ApiSessionDriver) that does not rely on cookies to Identify the session id ?.

### my situation:

I need to implement mobile API and track mobiles sessions using a custom header, for example `X-Session`, without relying on the Native cookies based driver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some unique token for each user into your database. When user login generate some token, save it to the database and send it back to the mobile device. After that for every request from the device this token have to sent as parameter.

Comment: this is valid for logged in users only, what I need is mocking the native session